# Prevent Payara from issuing JSESSIONID for path /

Tags: glassfish, payara, jsessionid, java-ee-8

We're running into an issue with multiple `JSESSIONID` being sent. Our web app is a JavaEE web app with Payara Server 5.2021.10.

The login page gets a `JSESSIONID` for the `/` path before logging in. After logging in, we redirect to `/my-app` and the browser is issued a second `JSESSIONID` for the `/my-app` path. The first cookie for `/` remains and is not refreshed, which could leave us vulnerable to a session fixation vulnerability.

Is there any config in `web.xml` or any Java side code that could prevent receiving a `JSESSIONID` before the user is actually logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help but I might have a solution for you. I will assume that your problem occurs in a production environment (same as mine).

I've recently faced several problems with *jsessionid* in my project. After reading many solutions on the internet that do not work, I just found I way to fix it. I hope it could help you too.

You just need to config SSL in your Payara. I've to follow this [tutorial](https://blog.payara.fish/configuring-ssl/tls-certificates-with-payara-server-and-lets-encrypt). There is just one piece of information that you have to change, when you create the file, instead of putting the file in the *`$PAYARA_HOME/glassfish/domains/production/config`* directory.
You change to
*`$PAYARA_HOME/glassfish/domains/production/`*

Just send a msg if you need more help :)